# Fantasy movie about a mansion with magical creatures that is similar to the 2008 series "Sanctuary"?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Here are some of the things I remember from the movie:

- The magical creatures were at risk - vague thought that they may be transdimensional.
- There was a lady - who may or may not have been in line for princess who was involved in a quest to save the creatures.
- There was a limited timeframe to save the creatures - maybe a week?
- There was a guy who was working with the lady.
- There might have been another lady helping out, who didn't appear until the end, who was the real heir.
- The main actors and actresses are all adults. I vaguely recall that at least one British actor was cast.

The action began with something getting loose and the protagonist being aware of the event, at some point the secondary lead meets up with her, reveals 'reality' to her, they go through some various trials as they work to save the creatures, maintain some balance?, eventually they succeed and all's well that ends well.
It is a love story, feel good, fun, but with action and suspense.

I think it was late 1990's or early 2000's and it might have been one of those TV movies.

To differentiate it somewhat from similarly themed shows - it is closer to *Sanctuary* or *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* than *Spiderwick Chronicles* or *Bridge to Terabithia*.

Comment: I'll need more details.

Mr Magorium's Wonder Emporium 2007 is similar to what you asked, but it is a shop, not a house   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457419/ 

There's also older film called The magic Toyshop https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097806/

There is also a movie called A Simple Wish 1997 that also fits your description https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120133/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt

  There is also The Spiderwick Chronicles which fits the timeframe https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=111&v=_yTZ8E3vbsE&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Some elements also match [A Bridge to Terebithia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_to_Terabithia_(2007_film))? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0398808/

Comment: @jo1storm and Alith, I was a bit too vague. I edited with some additional detail. I've not seen Mr. Magorium's Wonder Emporium, but that's not it. The others, the leads are too young. This movie had adult lead actress and actor. Otherwise, the themes are at a similar level of maturity as Spiderwick/Bridge to Terabithia.

Comment: Hm. Check this one out: A House with a clock in its walls  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQGA42-U0Ro  It is newer, though. 2018.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure you're looking for [**Princess**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1052352/) from 2008. From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/princess_2008):

> **A reclusive princess and a directionless young man embark on a quest to save the world's mythical creatures from becoming extinct in this romantic fantasy for the entire family.**

Takes place in a castle and IIRC she has to find someone next in line - a Healer or a Seeker or some such - **within a week** to take care of these creatures (which are mermaids and elves etc.). And it was indeed a TV movie (it aired on ABC) and is basically a feel-good love story. You can watch the trailer [here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x329bou).

[image: movie poster, princess in green dress lookinng at her reflection in the water]

Comment: Yup this is the one. The lady is the princess who takes care of a castle full of magical creatures who will lose her powers in a week. She needs to find her replacement with the help of the searcher. The guy is the searcher, but doesn't know it at first.

Answer (score 0):

[*Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Peregrine's_Home_for_Peculiar_Children_(film)) (2016) maybe?

Main character finds out that stories of his grandfather are true once his grandfather is killed by a monster. Travels to a Welsh village and through time. In the past, he meets certain "peculiar" children with magical powers.

The time bubble is being maintained by Miss Peregrine, an umbryne. At a certain moment in the movie, another umbryne joins them.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [The Borrowers(1997)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borrowers_(1997_film))?

Quote from wiki article:

> Young Pete Lender (Bradley Pierce) is setting up traps around his
>   house, explaining to his parents that things in their house are being
>   stolen, despite his parents believing they are simply misplaced.
>   However, it turns out that a family of tiny people ("Borrowers"), are
>   living in the house, borrowing stuff without being seen. Pod Clock
>   (Jim Broadbent) and his children, Arrietty (Flora Newbigin) and
>   Peagreen (Tom Felton), make their way through the kitchen to "borrow"
>   the radio's battery.
>
> Arrietty, while treating herself with some ice cream in the freezer,
>   is accidentally shut inside just as the Lenders return. Pod manages to
>   rescue Arietty, but jams the ice cube tube in the process and is
>   forced to leave one of his gadgets behind, which is found by Mr.
>   Lender. Meanwhile, the will of Mrs. Lender's aunt Mrs. Allabaster is
>   the only proof that the house rightfully belongs to the family, yet
>   their lawyer Ocious P. Potter (John Goodman) cannot find it and has
>   already made plans to demolish their house in order to build
>   condominiums on the land, and the Lenders have until Saturday to move
>   away.
>
> Arrietty is trapped by an astonished Pete, who explains to her that
>   the house is being demolished for want of Mrs. Allabaster's will,
>   meaning that both families will have to move. After Arrietty explains
>   the situation to her family, Pod reluctantly agrees to have the family
>   move to the new house, despite being somewhat upset that Arrietty has
>   defied so much about the way of the Borrowers. Unfortunately, during
>   the journey, Arrietty and Peagreen fall out of the moving truck and
>   make their way back to the old house, where they find the new house on
>   a map.

Tiny creatures - Check
House - Check
Limited timeframe - check
Something getting loose and protagonist becoming aware - Check

The only thing lacking is 2nd princess.